# php echo htmlspecialchar post error

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

Let me start by saying this is the first time I have touched php since college, and I am very limited in my knowledge. I followed a tutorial in order to implement a contact form on a bootstrap website for a client. Everything works except for the "message" field due to it being a textarea rather than an input. For testing I swapped the textarea with an input, and it worked fine. Is there another method of capturing the user entered text to post? It seems like something simple, but I have been struggling with it for hours, and can't seem to find a solution. I am using the following code for the message html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="Enter Your Message" ><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);?></textarea>
        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the php I am using, and it results in displaying the error message 'Please enter your message'

```
if ($_POST["submit"]) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $human = intval($_POST['human']);
    $from = 'bot@dtosolutions.com';
    $to = 'eric@ericbelldesigns.com';
    $subject = 'Message from Contact Form';

    $body ="From: $name\n E-mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

    //Check if name is entered
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $errName = 'Please enter your name';    
    }

    //Check if email is valid
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email';    
    }

    //Check if a message is entered
    if (!$_POST['message']) {
        $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';    
    }

    //Check if anti-bot test is correct
    if ($human !== 7) {
        $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';    
    }

    // If there are no errors - send the email
    if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
        if(mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';    
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message.</div>';       
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: You should have error reporting on. That would tell you that you have undefined indexs. Your `if (!$_POST['name']) {` is going to fail because there is no element with that name. Also note that since you are assigning the POST values to a variable you should use the variable(s) later in the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It showing the error message `Please Enter you Message` because your message is not posting to your php script. According to your code you're checking the `message` in this line

```
if (!$_POST['message']) {
    $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';    
}
```

but there are no input or textarea field named `message`. For posting your message to your php script you should change your `textarea` name `Enter Your Message` to `message` and then it will work perfectly.

Comment: Thank you so much man! That was exactly my issue. I don't know how I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to print the message with `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);?>`, but I see some possible problems here.

- There is not an input with name `message`. The text area's name is
  `Enter Your Message`. And name with spaces will be converted to
  underscores in $_POST. That means you need to refer to
  `$_POST["Enter_Your_Message"]`.
- I suggest you check if an input is filled before assign its value to a variable.